# Jarsigner : sign standalone jar with Developer ID certificate

Tags: java, macos, jarsigner, osx-gatekeeper, apple-developer

While I can use `Developer ID` certificates from **Apple** to sign **.app** and **.dmg**, I'm wondering if there is way to use it to sign the **standalone jar** version (click & run), and also a couple of eclipse plugins (jars).

I sign the jars with **Comodo Cert** and it works fine in windows, but when running the standalone jar in **MacOS** , **GateKeeper** blocks it.

All Apple Develper certificates `(Developer ID Application, mac Developer, Developer Id Installer ...)` don't seem to support jarsigner , is there a way to sign jars for **MacOS** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't sign a jar with an Apple certificate. However, you can convert your jar to a MacOS application (e.g. with `jar2app`) and then sign the application.